# Do visa officers consider my Occupation on my passport?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration

My occupation on my passport is written house wife. Does that affect me getting a scholarship and student visa?

Comment: Whether you get a scholarship will depend upon the rules and regulations of the school or entity or person offering the scholarship. Whether you get a student visa will depend upon the rules and regulations of the country to which you apply. Both applications will require far more information about you than a notation of "housewife" on your passport; it's likely that your occupation as listed in the passport will have no effect.

Comment: In many (most?) countries quite a few details are rarely or never updated, like the occupation or your address. That’s one of the reasons many countries just no longer include that info at all in passports. So I doubt much attention is given to them (unless maybe your passport is brand new and the information clearly contradicts other statements made in your application).

Comment: most countries don't mention "occupation" at all on your passport, I doubt most countries would consider it in any way.

Comment: In Australia, no effect. It would be understood that the occupation status is required in your home country; and that housewife is one of the default occupations.